# How to work on single project using two different computers using Git?

Tags: git

I am learning Git.

I am developing a project on computer A. I am moving this project from computer A to computer B using pen drive. I pushed all my project files to repo from computer A. I HAVE SAME FILES ON COMPUTER B.

How can I merge my repository with computer B?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're using a removable disk, you don't need to do anything to merge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to need first `git clone` command for **Computer B**

Example

```
 git clone git@github.com:whatever folder-name
```

If you update/change **B Computer** after clone you have to need `git commit -am "message"` and then `git push`.

Now you decide to work on **Computer A** first you have to need `git fetch` command and then `git pull` .

You can check status of your repository by writing command `git status`

Same Command will be applicable when you aging starting work on **Computer B**

Thank You....

Comment: Where I should use clone command? Do I have to use git init command before? Do I need to run git bash on the directory where my project is saved? Please help.

Comment: No! you have to need `git init` just first time when you determined to create a repository

Comment: `git clone` only used when you have a repository from **Computer A**

Comment: Thank you Momin. Can you suggest me some online tutorials?

Comment: Of course ! Why Not! Start with Basic to Mid then Advance ! okay

http://tutorialzine.com/2016/06/learn-git-in-30-minutes/

Comment: I have Premium Books & Video tutorial also

Comment: Thank you so much Momin.

Comment: 25 beginner to mid level  Git Tutorial @JayV

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEGIFZDyszA&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAKWClAD_iKpNC0bGHxGhcx

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new branch and then merge pull request. [Create pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/)

Comment: Thank you, Asher. I find Momin's answer more appropriate.